# Assetic not generating any files

Tags: twig, assetic

I am using Assetic with Twig but not the symfony2 framework.

Here's how the project is set up

```
/site
   /template
      /css

/public_html
  /css
```

The raw css is stored under `/site/template/css` and I want assetic to minify the css and output it to `/public_html/css`.

Here's how assetic is set up as a twig extension

```
$factory = new AssetFactory(//absolute path to `/site/template/`);
$factory->setDefaultOutput(//absolute path to `/public_html/`);
$factory->setDebug(false);
$twig->addExtension(new AsseticExtension($factory));
```

Then in my template:

```
{% stylesheets 'css/screen.css'  output='css/*' %}
  <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

I can see that assetic has generated a unique url in the final output:

```
<link href="css/00da241.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

However, if I look in `/public_html/css`, the files are never generated!

I am using a Windows 7 server with apache and PHP has no issues writing files anywhere.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've done here is asking assetic to generate URL's to assets (using twig).

But assets urls don't point to any file yet. You still have to generate them, using a *dump* script:

```php
<?php

use Assetic\AssetWriter;
use Assetic\Extension\Twig\TwigFormulaLoader;
use Assetic\Extension\Twig\TwigResource;
use Assetic\Factory\LazyAssetManager;

$am = new LazyAssetManager($factory);

// enable loading assets from twig templates
$am->setLoader('twig', new TwigFormulaLoader($twig));

// loop through all your templates
foreach ($templates as $template) {
    $resource = new TwigResource($twigLoader, $template);
    $am->addResource($resource, 'twig');
}

$writer = new AssetWriter('/path/to/web');
$writer->writeManagerAssets($am);
```

This script uses twig templates to define **which** files to dump.
You will have to define the `$templates` variable and the `$twig` variables of course.

Comment: Thanks florian :) Is there an alternative to running the dump script during development? It's not very efficient to have to run the script everytime I change an asset and then test in the browser.

Comment: Assetic is so flexible, and in the same time so complex that it's hard to say :) But this doc could help you https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/blob/master/docs/en/build.md

Comment: As I am using twig, I would like to stay away from writing my own output scripts :) I see that there a symfony console script that watches the folder and compiles any changes, however, as I am not using symfony, that is out of question at the moment. However, I will hunt around to see if I can find a solution. There are also certain things in the symfony bundle that I like: cache busting and basePath, so I will probably have to look at implementing that myself. I will mark this as correct as this solved my problem of why the files aren't being created :)

Comment: Im having the same problems. The documentation of assetic is very bad sadly. It consists of loads of snippets that dont connect. So if you find more info, plz update your question ;)

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! What represents the `$templates` variables? All of my computable templates? only layout templates? What are best practices or use cases?

Comment: @tzi I think it would be all templates that contains assetic related code.